# problem with update the counter value

Tags: java

I having problem to update the counter (integer value).
this is the definitions of the class:

```
public class Item_Actions 
{
    private final int MAX_ITEMS = 100;
    private Item myItem[];
    private int counter;

    public Item_Actions()
    {
        myItem  = new Item[MAX_ITEMS];
        counter++;      
    }

    //Constructor add item into the menu (Description, type & price of Item)

    public void addItem(Item itm)
    {
        myItem[counter] = itm;
        counter++;
    }.......
```

Now everytime I call the addItem constructor from another class, the counter always stays on zero.
What causing it and how do I save the data inside?

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a `java.util.List` to store your items?

Comment: `addItem` is **not** a constructor. It's a method. By the way, the mentioned problem is not visible in the as far posted code and information. It looks fine (although the `counter++` in the (real!) constructor is unnecessary). It lies somewhere else. Be more precise. Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, you are right.
Peter - no special reason, it wasn't requeired.

Comment: @Edan: Did the accepted answer really solve your problem? Making it static will lead to unwanted (as I understand it) behavior if you make another instance of your class...

Comment: it seems to work just fine now...

Comment: If you make the `counter` static, then everytime when you do `new Item_Actions()`, it won't be reset! Your actual problem was caused by something else. That is works doesn't mean that it's the right approach. If this is homework, you will undoubtely lose points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert the `static` keyword in before declaration of the variable `counter`. That is

```
 private static int counter=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The counter should be `static` - you want to limit the number of instantiations, so the counter shouldn't be an instance-variable. Instead it should be "global" - i.e. `static`.
Your array should be `static` as well.

Instead of using a counter and an array, you can use an `ArrayList`.

That all said, avoid `static` fields - instead look for the problem in your other code.

Comment: sorry, my bad. removed that part.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, this only shifts the problem. Imho he misspoke when he said "constructor".